# Read all files from a folder with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

For reading a file from a folder it's quite straightforward. The file was in .md format and transformed to html format before sending it with POST:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const showdown = require('showdown');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

converter = new showdown.Converter();

app.post('/api/world', (req, res) => {
  fs = require('fs');
  fs.readFile(
    __dirname + '/posts/my-file.md',
    'utf8',
    function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      text = data;
      html = converter.makeHtml(text);
      res.send(html);
    }
  );
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Now, what happens when there are more files in that folder? For getting those files titles I did it like:

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir(__dirname + '/posts', (err, files) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else {
    console.log('\nCurrent directory filenames:');
    files.forEach((file) => {
      console.log(file);
    });
  }
});
```

The above code logs the titles of the files in that folder.

The problem appears when I want to read those files and send them as I did with the first single file at the beginning. This is how I've tried:

```
app.post('/api/world', (req, res) => {
  fs = require('fs');
  fs.readdir(__dirname + '/posts', (err, files) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else {
      console.log('\nCurrent directory filenames:');
      files.forEach((file) => {
        // console.log(file);
        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/posts/' + file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
          console.log(file);
          if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
          }
          text = data;
          html = converter.makeHtml(text);
          res.send(html);
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

It throws this error:

```
        res.send(html);
        ^

ReferenceError: res is not defined
```

I don't get it, `res` was defined at the top of the POST request. What's wrong with it and how can it be changed to work?

Answer (score 3):

You only get ONE `res.send()` per request so if you're using `res.send()` you will have to accumulate the content and then send all the content at once.

And, since you have multiple asynchronous operations all in flight at once, you will also have to keep track of when they are all done.  This would be easiest using promises with `async/await`.

Assuming you want to just concatenate all the HTML you produce, you can do something like this:

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');

app.post('/api/world', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let html = "";
        const basePath = path.join(__dirname, 'posts');
        const files = await fsp.readdir(basePath);
        for (let f of files) {
            const fileData = await fsp.readFile(path.join(basePath, f));
            html += converter.makeHtml(fileData);
        }
        res.send(html);
    } catch(e) {
        // log error and send error response
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

Comment: looks nice but I would like them as separate files because that's how they are used in the front-end. is it possible to do it without concatenation?

Comment: @dadsa - I do not understand what you're trying to send to the client so I don't really know what else to recommend until you can explain what you're trying to accomplish.  You get to send ONE response per request.  So, you can't call `res.send()` multiple times.  You can control how you concatenate the HTML together (if you want some delimiter between them or something).  For me to help further, I need to know what you're actually trying to send to the client in your one response.

Comment: all the files  in the folder are .md files. In node.js I want to convert them to html (which is done) and send those files to the front-end. In the front-end I'm creating new routes for each of these pages (at the moment it is working with one file because I don't know how to send multiple files). is it more clear now?

Comment: @dadsa - Sorry, still don't understand.  Routes are usually something you create on the server, not in the client.  Still don't understand what you're trying to send to the client.  Is the client wanting to "download" and save these multiple files separately?  What is it going to do with them?

Comment: something like an array these files would be useful so I can iterate through them. I'm creating the routes in the front-end with `react-router-dom`